# Can class-specific deallocation functions be used in constant expressions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, constexpr, delete-operator

Can I define one of class-specific deallocation functions and use it in a constant expression?

For example a destroying delete:

```
#include <new>

struct A {
    constexpr void operator delete(A *, std::destroying_delete_t);
};

struct B : A {};

constexpr void A::operator delete(A *p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
    ::delete static_cast<B*>(p);
}

constexpr bool foo() {
    A *p = new B;
    delete p;
    return true;
}

static_assert( foo() );
```

GCC and MSVC do accept it, however Clang complains:

```
error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
note: call to class-specific 'operator delete'
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/47h1Y4sr3

Which behavior is correct?

Comment: Regardless of whether the `delete` expression using  the `operator delete` in the class is permitted in constant expressions, your `operator delete` will always have undefined behavior because when it is entered the lifetime of the `A` object was already ended by the calling `delete` expression. You then try to call `delete` on it again, which will cause UB when trying to call the destructor again out-of-lifetime.

Comment: It would be well-behaved as a destroying delete.

Comment: GCC and MSVC behave differently btw: GCC considers the `operator delete` as a normal function call in the constant expression while MSVC simply ignores its body. See https://godbolt.org/z/jWWxYGd11.

Comment: Now it has the same problem in a different form. You are still calling the destructor twice: Once in `static_cast<B*>(p)->~B();` and once implicitly by `::delete p;` (and the latter with the wrong type as well). It should be `::delete static_cast<B*>(p);`.

Comment: Without the `static_cast<B*>(p)->~B();`.

Comment: @user17732522, many thanks for all your comments, indeed I made a few mistakes in writing example program, which are fixed now with your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[expr.const]/5, bullet points 18-19 state that constant evaluation may not encounter:

> - a new-expression ([expr.new]), unless the selected allocation function is a replaceable global allocation function ([new.delete.single], [new.delete.array]) and the allocated storage is deallocated within the evaluation of E;
> - a delete-expression ([expr.delete]), unless it deallocates a region of storage allocated within the evaluation of E;

This does not specify that the selected *deallocation* function must be a replaceable global deallocation function; as long as it ends up calling such a deallocation function if necessary to satisfy the preceding bullet point, your code is valid.

A further possibly-motivating [example](https://godbolt.org/z/G7x89o7K9):

```cpp
#include <new>
struct A {
    int& r;
    constexpr void operator delete(A* p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
        p->r = 1;
        ::delete(p);
    }
};
constexpr int foo() {
    int i = 0;
    delete new A{i};
    return i;
}
static_assert(foo() == 1);
```

An interesting question is raised by the [following](https://godbolt.org/z/86P3rY49j):

```cpp
#include <new>
struct B {
    int** q;
    constexpr void operator delete(B* p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
        **p->q = 1;
        delete p->q;
    }
};
constexpr int bar() {
    int j = 0;
    B b{new int*(&j)};
    delete &b;
    return j;
}
static_assert(bar() == 1);
```

That is, does it matter *which* region of storage the delete-expression deallocates, or is it expected to be the region of storage corresponding to the object to which the operand of the delete-expression points? Perhaps the current language should be replaced by its inversion:

> - a delete-expression ([expr.delete]), <del>unless it</del> **which** deallocates a region of storage **not** allocated within the evaluation of E;